# Is there a US state outline template for google maps?

Tags: google-maps

I'm planning a website to let users highlight an individual state. Is there a template or a script I can run to automatically outline the states?

Kind of like this http://www.motherjones.com/politics/2011/11/states-federal-taxes-spending-charts-maps

I feel like there HAS to be a template or something out there but I cant find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Those maps](http://www.motherjones.com/politics/2011/11/states-federal-taxes-spending-charts-maps) are using fusion tables.  The polygons for the US states are publicly available in the [Natural Earth data set](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_query_sidebarF_local.html?country=United%20States%20of%20America).  Another option (for [regular Google Maps](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http%3a%2F%2Fwww.geocodezip.com%2Fgeoxml3_test%2Fus_states.xml&hl=en&sll=32.824552,-117.108978&sspn=0.691256,0.883026&t=m&z=3)) is [KML](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_us_states_kml_test.html).